# Issues with Visual Studio 2010 project creation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I create a simple Win32 projects, edit the configuration and add new platform configurations (x64).  I then batch rebuild my project and I get this output:

```
------ Rebuild All started: Project: Skribe, Configuration: Release x64 ------
  main.c
  Generating code
  Finished generating code
  Skribe.vcxproj -> D:\Dev\Skribe\Build\VS2010\Solutions\..\..\..\Output\Bin\x64\Release\Skribe.exe
------ Rebuild All started: Project: Skribe, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
  main.c
  Skribe.vcxproj -> D:\Dev\Skribe\Build\VS2010\Solutions\..\..\..\Output\Bin\x64\Debug\Skribe.exe
  Skribe.vcxproj -> D:\Dev\Skribe\Build\VS2010\Solutions\..\..\..\Output\Bin\x64\Debug\Skribe.exe
------ Rebuild All started: Project: Skribe, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
  main.c
  Generating code
  Finished generating code
  Skribe.vcxproj -> D:\Dev\Skribe\Build\VS2010\Solutions\..\..\..\Output\Bin\Win32\Release\Skribe.exe
------ Rebuild All started: Project: Skribe, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
  main.c
  Skribe.vcxproj -> D:\Dev\Skribe\Build\VS2010\Solutions\..\..\..\Output\Bin\Win32\Debug\Skribe.exe
========== Rebuild All: 4 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

The debug x64 build outputs the exe creation message twice and I cannot figure out why.  This worries because of a related question I asked where a rebuild actually fails but a clean/build succeeds.

Does anyone know why the extra message is shown?  I've done nothing else other than create a solution, exe project, add x64 configuration and batch rebuild.